# Create Multilevel XML using multilevel join Linq

Tags: c#, .net, xml, asp.net-mvc, linq

[image]

I am trying to create XML with Linq, however I have multiple table nested as above, so I have to create Elements with definite id selected from Table1 and so on, so how do I create with multiple joins as above diagram?? or should I iteratively repeat and increase the joins as above??

```
XDocument xDocument = new XDocument(new XElement("Table1",
            from cs in Table1
            join c in Table2
                on cs.table1_id equals c.fk_table1_id
            join ml in Table3
                on c.table2_id equals ml.fk_table2_id
            join s in Table4
                on ml.table3_id equals s.fk_table3_id
            select new XElement("Table2",
                new XAttribute("NAME", c.name),
                new XAttribute("TYPE", c.type),
                new XAttribute("ID", c.id)),

                //stucked here

                new XElement("Table3",
                select new XElement("Table3",
                        new XAttribute("WIDTH", ml.height),
                        new XAttribute("HEIGHT", ml.width)),
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: It seems more like a *write-it-for-me*, rather than a question.

Comment: @L.B can you check the edits